# Java NoSuchMethodError exception

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.logging.LocalLogs.getNullLogger()Lorg/openqa/selenium/logging/LocalLogs;
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:332)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:328)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at com.gravitant.test.Sample.main(Sample.java:10)
```

Below is my code:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();  
          System.out.println("Opening FF");  
          driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please add some detail to your question. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you please provide the version of Selenium you are using ?

Comment: 2.45 Selenium server jar

Comment: What version of selenium-java do you have in your classpath?

Comment: selenium-java 2.45.0

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue logged on SeleniumHQ.

The explanation is :
["you have a java classpath issue somewhere. The method does exist and has existed for quite some time"](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/430)

So as I see it, you have a program that thinks it is getting and old version of Selenium, but it is getting a new one.